# What are systemd *.device units actually waiting for?

Tags: systemd, mount

I've got a system that get's stuck when systemd tries to mount a filesystem.  It fails on a dependency times out. The dependency is `dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-cb\x2drootfs.device` where the device being mounted is `/dev/disk/by-label/cb-rootfs`.

```
systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-cb\x2drootfs.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-cb\x2drootfs.device/start timed out.
```

Nothing stops me mounting the system with:

```
mount -av
```

So in this case it seems that systemd is waiting for the wrong thing, since the device is obviously there and ready to be mounted.

---

What might make this complex is that the root filesystem is an overlayfs involving the same device. In simple terms, initramfs is doing this:

```
mount /dev/disk/by-label/cb-rootfs /host
mount -o loop /host/rootfs/foo.squashfs /ro
mount -t overlay overlay lowerdir=/ro,upperdir=/host/writable,workdir=/host/workdir /root
```

`/root` is then the root file system ready for systemd to start mounting from `/etc/fstab`:

Then `/etc/fstab` tries to mount

```
/dev/disk/by-label/cb-rootfs /host ext4 defaults 0 0
```

---

As I say I can `mount -av` and Linux has absolutely no problem mounting `/dev/disk/by-label/cb-rootfs.  But systemd is aparently waiting endlessly for it to become ready in some way.

**What is systemd waiting for?** how can I avoid it waiting like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to my question on systemd mailing lists I got [this response](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2023-September/049530.html):

> Mantas Mikulėnas
>
> .device units wait for *udev* to broadcast the uevent about that device
> being added, which happens after udev has 1. received the initial
> kernel uevent (either real or produced by
> systemd-udev-trigger.service) and 2. finished processing all its
> .rules for that device (which means everything that rules launched
> from RUN= must have exited, etc).
>
> Only devices that udev rules have tagged with TAG+="systemd" will
> produce .device units; generally 99-systemd.rules will add that to
> disk devices.
>
> If any of the rules have marked the device with
> ENV{SYSTEMD_READY}="0", the .device unit will keep waiting until
> another event removes that.

In my case it turned out udev was not installed properly or corrupted so despite the device being available in /dev systemd was still waiting on a signal from udev.

Simply reinstalling udev fixed the problem for me.